# Constraining the generic input parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I've designed the following interface.

```
public interface IProcess<ICommand> { void Run(); }
```

However, Resharper remarks that it doesn't really matter what I call my input parameter, be that `ICommand` or `TWhatEverElse`.

Now, it's easily recognizable by the name I've chosen that what I **intended** was to set a limitation of the type of the generic parameter to be one that is implemented, derived or simply just of type *ICommand*

Sadly, the stubborn computer does what I ask it to and not what I mean it to so I need some help. Using the notation of `: where` won't do me much good because I want to constrain to an interface (and all of it's minions).

Can I constrain the type that is sent into the crocodile braces and if so how?

## Edit

I've added *where* clause and arrived at the following.

```
public interface IProcess<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand { }
```

However, I seem to be missing something still. The implementing class is as follows.

```
public class Processo : IProcess<Commando> { }

public class Commando : ICommand { }
```

However, the compiler claims that it's not going to fly because *Commando* isn't convertible to *ICommand*. What do I miss here?!

Comment: Did you research this?  Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Ha, apparently I did not. At least not sufficiently well. That's what one gets when one assumes what one's going to find out... Shame on me. Still, a good question, come to think.

Comment: So you now know how to go about this?

Comment: `IProcess<ICommand>` *does not* imply that you want the generic argument to implement `ICommand`. The way you wrote it `ICommand` is simply the name of the generic argument. What you probably wanted is `public interface IProcess<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand`. However, it's still unclear why is the interface generic if you don't make any use of `TCommand` anyway.

Comment: @haim770 I do use it. Just not in the smallest possible example.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten, `void Run(TCommand cmd);` is still a "smallest possible example" :)

Comment: @haim770 You're wrong as to **the smallest**, hihi. But you're right - I should considering using the parameter so it doesn't raise feeling of me being totally off to begin with. You might enjoy my edit, then. (Not being obnoxious - just joking.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a constraint using the `where` keyword:

```
public interface IProcess<T> where T : ICommand { void Run(); }
```

as documented [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: Please see edit. I used your link and it helped but I'm still stuck on something.

Comment: I saw your edit.  I've tested your code and it works just fine for me.  So something else is going on.  One thing you haven't shown in your question is `ICommand`, so maybe there's something not-so-straightforward going on with that.  Without showing that to us, though, I can't really say.

Comment: I trust you have. Need to keep looking into it. As far I can tell, there's nothing weird going on there but apparently there's something. I'll design some own classes and keep on trying. +1 for being thorough.

Comment: You're awesome! Turns out *ICommand* is declared in *NServiceBus* **but also** in *System.Windows.Input*. So I was looking at a different class than what I thought. Problem gone!